# QT Creator with MinGQ 5.3.0. How can I use the -static flag?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am QT Creator with MinGW 5.3.0 32bit.
In the CLI I use g++ hello.cpp -o hello.exe -static. So I don't have to copy ove the two dlls to my program folder.
Is there a way to specify the -static flag in the .pro file or compiler settings?
I tried:
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS =+ -static
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -static

as told by another party and it didn't work.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I suspect `-static` is a linker flag, not a compiler flag.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was a compiler flag hence why it didn't work. I passed it as QMAKE_LFLAG += -static and it worked.